# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE not working due to date field

Tags: php, mysql, csv-import

I am trying to import data from a huge csv file. I am trying following code but it dosen't work due to it break the query because of a date field value in csv file.

```
$conn = new \PDO("mysql:host=host_name;dbname=db_name;", "username", "password", array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING
));
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'services.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE service_ready_list FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS (@col1,@col2,@col3) set service_number=@col1, service_name=@col2, ready_date=STR_TO_DATE(@col3, '%d/%m/%Y')";
try {
    $conn->prepare($sql)->execute();
    //print_r($conn->errorInfo());
    echo "File import completed....\n";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
    echo "\n Error occured\n";
}
```

`service_ready_list.ready_date` is a `DATE` field.
When execute aboove script nothing inserted into table and also there is no any error displaying. If I remove `ready_date=STR_TO_DATE(@col3, '%d/%m/%Y')` it is working fine.

Also I tried with known data set with some empty values for third column in csv file, then also it works. So I guess that there is an invalid date that prevent above query running in the actual data set. I also tried following code but it also didn't work for me.

```
ready_date=if(STR_TO_DATE(@col3, '%d/%m/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE(@col3, '%d/%m/%Y'),'0000-00-00')
```

Comment: You can disable strict mode. Then the NULL values for date/datetime fields will be handled without error.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Currently it can save NULL value into service_ready_list.ready_date field.

Comment: But, it is also about the '0000-00-00' which is not NULL.

Comment: @MarkusZeller when I just use 
ready_date=STR_TO_DATE(@col3, '%d/%m/%Y') it automatically set 0000-00-00 for empty csv fields